# Loading data with vanilla D3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm new to Javascript, and I can't seem to get the hang of Promises in the context of D3.js. For example, the following code should fill the 'data' const with my formatted csv data, but instead fills with a promise wrapping my formatted csv data.

```
data = (async function(){
  //the problem line
  const data = await d3.csv("{{url_for('static', filename='d3test.csv')}}");
  
  const columns = data.columns.slice(1);
  return {
    y: "Sales",
    series: data.map(d => ({
      name: d.Variations.replace(/, ([\w-]+).*/, " $1"),
      values: columns.map(k => +d[k])
    })),
    dates: columns.map(d3.utcParse("%Y-%m-%d"))
  };
})();
```

The same line in the Observable.hq that worked was:

```
const data = d3.csvParse(await FileAttachment("d3test.csv").text());
```

I'd like to use vanilla javascript, not an observable.hq embedding.

Edit: I'm using D3 v5.min

Comment: Does it work if you put just a url to the file in the d3.csv function?

Comment: Which version of d3 are you using? Before v5, `d3.csv` was not thenable (did not return a Promise)

Comment: That's the expected behavior. The [return value](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function#Return_value) of an [async function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) is by definition a Promise. It's important to keep in mind that ObservableHQ is not pure JavaScript, though! It looks like JS and in many ways behaves like it, still, it's more of a dialect with its own twists and turns.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem by deciding to actually embed my Observable.hq notebook. People will say "Observable.hq isn't vanilla Javascript", but neglect to mention that most D3.js tutorials and references use Observable.hq... so there's little chance to learn proper Javascript (oxymoron much?).

Instrumental to the solution were:
[Observable: Advanced Embedding and Downloading](https://observablehq.com/@observablehq/downloading-and-embedding-notebooks)
[Observable Common examples on Github](https://github.com/observablehq/examples) (the custom data one)

my working code in the Flask template (that's in addition to a working Observable Notebook) was:

```
        const main = new Runtime().module(notebook, Inspector.into("#graphDiv"));

        (async function() {
          main.redefine("data", (async function(){
                  const data = await d3.csv('{{url_for("static", filename=g.pt)}}');
                  const columns = data.columns.slice(1);
                  return {
                    y: "Sales",
                    series: data.map(d => ({
                      name: d.Variations.replace(/, ([\w-]+).*/, " $1"),
                      values: columns.map(k => +d[k])
                    })),
                    dates: columns.map(d3.utcParse("%Y-%m-%d"))
                  };
                })())
        })();
        </script>
```

That code loads the whole notebook, then replaces a single cell/variable. There's not much different and I'm still a bit confused, but it works now. Although it's worth noting that the other cells needed covering up - accomplished using CSS visibility. Still a hacky solution.